# How to track data consumed by each application using VPN in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, networkextension, nevpnmanager

Recently I downloaded My Data Mgr from app store and they seem to track data usage of each app through vpn.
I don't have enough knowledge in vpn and setting up one. But I guess they are setting up a local vpn and tunneling all the network data through this vpn and analysing the data for each app.

Can anyone help me understand this workflow and also how can I achieve it.

Here is the screen shot of VPN config used by My data manager

I know it's a very broad question, But I want to be pointed at a specific direction.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809680/iphone-vpn-to-track-usage), please don't mark it as duplicate. There was no proper answer given there.

[image]

Comment: Did you achieve success in your research? I'm currently looking for the same solution

Comment: i also search for this code, but i only get data for device usage.

Comment: I have the same question still I did not any solution for this :(

Comment: @antonioyaphiar can you share your logic for data for device usage

Comment: @AnupGupta i get it by using device data log, just moved from old company *i left the code there. Sorry